# angular service to factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization

I need to remake this functoin 'i18n' to a factory but so i return a value instead of just setting it with this.

Thanks in advance!

```
services.service('i18n', function() {
    var self = this;
    this.setLanguage = function(language) {
        $.i18n.properties({
            name: 'messages',
            path: 'i18n/',
            mode: 'map',
            language: language,
            callback: function() {
                self.language = language;
            }
        });
    };
    this.setLanguage('nl');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up your service like this:

```
myApp.service('LangService', function() {
    var setLang = function(lang) {
        // return whatever you want
    }

    return {
        setLang: setLang
    };
});
```

Then you can call your method `setLang` from anywhere:

```
LangService.setLang('nl');
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I know how the structure of a service looks like bit I can only return it through this, I need a factory so I can inject the factory into the controller-class

Comment: You can `$inject` this in your controllers. Did you set it up right for your app?

Comment: yes there is nothing wrong with that but when I inject the current function, all of the other angular stuff wont show up anymore...

Comment: could you create a fiddle?